# Constraining Rust Generics to custom data types

Tags: generics, rust, enums

Consider the following struct that I have built. The purpose of this
struct is to contain one of the following data types in the ***layers*** variable, either a ***2D Vector of Networks***, or a ***1D Vector of Meshes***. My original plan was to set the ***layers*** variable to an Enum (shown below), however I would like to append to the value in the enum after it is set - which I don't
think enum allows without copying?

Which brings me to my question: How can I define a ***layers*** as a
generic value and constrain it to only allow a ***2D Vector of
Networks***, or a ***1D Vector of Meshes***? Even if working with
Enums is possible, I imagine using a generic would be much cleaner.

```
 pub(crate) struct Mapping {
     layers: NodeDefinition
 }
 
 impl Mapping {
     pub(crate) fn new(node_definition: NodeDefinition) -> Mapping {
         Mapping {
             layers: node_definition
         }
     }
 }
 
 pub(crate) enum NodeDefinition {
     NODE(Vec<Vec<Network>>),
     LEAF(Vec<Mesh>),
 }
```

Comment: I think an enum is the right choice here, and of course you can mutate the contents of an enum, provided you have mutable access.

Comment: A few side notes: enum variants are upper CamelCase by default. Representing a two-dimensional array as `Vec<Vec<...>>` isn't the most efficient approach – it's usually better to use a flat `Vec<...>` and provide suitable access methods, so you can index it with two indices.

Comment: Thanks, It's good to know I was on the right track with enums. It also makes sense that having a 1D vec would be more efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time I managed to get a solution working. The solution was define a "dummy" trait which, at the moment does nothing (but will in the future). I later defined the type to be a generic that implemented the dummy trait. Here is some of that code:

The solution below constrains the generic type "T" to either a Node or a Mesh.

```
pub(crate) struct Network<T> {
    guid: Uuid,
    input: bool,
    output: bool,
    subnet: T,
}

impl<T: Subnet> Network<T> {
    pub(crate) fn new(subnet: T) -> Network<T> {
        Network {
            guid: Uuid::new_v4(),
            input: true,
            output: true,
            subnet,
        }
    }
}

//// Concerned with Mesh Struct
pub(crate) struct Mesh {
}

impl Subnet for Mesh {}

impl Mesh {
    pub(crate) fn new() -> Mesh {
        Mesh {
        }
    }
}

/// Concerned with Node Struct
pub(crate) struct Node {
}

impl Subnet for Node {}

impl Node {
    pub(crate) fn new() -> Node {
        Node {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the advantage of this over an enum?

Comment: I plan on adding specialized functions for both the Node and Mesh that carry out different instructions. As far as I am aware, enums do not allow this? The second reason (just a personal preference) is I find this syntax cleaner. Additionally, referencing the Node and Mesh values through traits does not require the .borrow_mut operator, which will just keep my code a little bit cleaner. I am by no means an "expert" at rust, but these are the benefits as I understand them.